# Php unit test gives error in default laravel application

Tags: laravel, phpunit

in default laravl application when I run phpunit it always gives me the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function each() in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Util\Getopt.php:80
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(239): PHPUnit_Util_Getopt::getopt(Array, 'd:c:hv', Array)
#1 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(138): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleArguments(Array)
#2 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(129): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)
#3 C:\xampp\php\phpunit(46): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
#4 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Util\Getopt.php on line 80

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function each() in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Util\Getopt.php:80
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(239): PHPUnit_Util_Getopt::getopt(Array, 'd:c:hv', Array)
#1 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(138): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleArguments(Array)
#2 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(129): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)
#3 C:\xampp\php\phpunit(46): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
#4 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Util\Getopt.php on line 80
```

here is my phpunit phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory>tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory>tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <source>
        <include>
            <directory>app</directory>
        </include>
    </source>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <!-- <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/> -->
        <!-- <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/> -->
        <env name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

I tries to do composer update to see if anthing will change but it still giving me the same error

Comment: What's your php version and phpunit version?

Comment: my php version is 8.2.0, and phpunit is 10.4

Comment: oh so where are you using `each()` in `Getopt.php`? it's deprecated [phpdocs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.each.php). Also can you share your `phpunit.xml` file in the question?

Comment: I am not using it, its the default files came with xampp and Laravel, where can I find the phpunit.xml I can't find it in xampp nor Laravel

Comment: I found it, I'll paste it

Comment: Did you change anything in the `composer.json`? So it's the standard phpunit.xml, can you try removing vendor folder and reinstalling `rm -rf vendor` and  `composer install` since it seems like compatibility issue.

Comment: It doesn't work, the same problem. I think I did a composer update, which will change composer.json, but the error appear even before the composer update

Comment: oh sorry retry `rm -rf vendor` also remove `rm composer.lock` and `composer install`

Comment: Also the same, it's an entirely strange thing, I'll try to recreate the project, thank you

Comment: Nothing at all worked, I created a new Laravel application and didn't add any library and the same error occurred

Comment: What PHP and Laravel versions are you using? What is your `composer.json`?